# Jquery mobile Listview show only first element

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this page coded with php and jquery mobile. It gets an input and queries the database and then populates a listview. Everything works perfectly but the problem is that it only shows the *first element* of the listview. It should return multiple data-role="page" elements as search results.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
            <?php while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3><?php echo $products['Product_name'] ; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $products['Product_price'] ; ?></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, your HTML is invalid because you cannot have block level elements like `h3` and `p` inside inline elements, such as `a`. Secondly, your PHP is missing the closing brace of the `while` statement.

Comment: this is only the part of the code which show the result in a DIV and it works .and you can put these blocks h3 and p inside <a> i saw that in a tutorial !

Comment: Actually I've just checked and you're right, if you're using HTML5 you can now have block level elements inside inline. In XHTML this was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the While statement, I can't see the closing bracket }

You need to use the following code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
            <?php while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3><?php echo $products['Product_name'] ; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $products['Product_price'] ; ?></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
           <? }?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: that wasnt the problem . i actualy did close it before closeing </body> i just didnt copy that in my question . my problem have something to do with that data-role . i need to show multiple results and it only show the first one !